# Space causing problem which building onClick function

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I have function where I read from a mysql table a set of value. Part of my codes is like this. The problem why I need to use fully php here is this a ajax called page.

```
echo "<tr id='gridRow'>
 <td >$count</td>
 <td> <input type='checkbox' onClick=selectAndUpdate('$row1[size]')></td>
 <td> {$row1[SerialNo]}</td> 
 <td> {$row1[InHouseBranding]}</td> 
 <td> {$row1[BrandCode]}</td> 
 <td> {$row1[size]}</td> 
 <td> {$row1[Pattern]}</td>  
 <td> {$row1[EntryStatus]}</td>   
 </tr>";
```

A sample row generated is as below can you notice this line  why the same value appear properly in the  21060R 22.567 but in the previous line is showing me like this 22.567')="" onclick="selectAndUpdate('21060R"> any idea?

```
<tr id="gridRow">
<td>1</td>
<td>
<input type="checkbox" 22.567')="" onclick="selectAndUpdate('21060R">
</td>
<td> EA12</td>
<td> BOR1</td>
<td> GY</td>
<td> 21060R 22.567</td>
<td> HMG 2020</td>
<td> New</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The generated code seems unrelated to the code the `echo` produces, notice int the `echo` it is written `type='checkbox'` while in the output its `type="checkbox"` (notice the quotes). make sure that you suspect the right echo to be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You need to quote your js and escape those quotes.

```
<td> <input type='checkbox' onClick=\"selectAndUpdate('$row1[size]')\"></td>
```

IF your writing complex html like this its better to use a string manipulation function like `sprintf` or `strtr`:

```
$html = '<tr id="gridRow">
 <td >%s</td>
 <td> <input type="checkbox" onClick="selectAndUpdate(\'%s\')"></td>
 <td>%s</td> 
 <td>%s</td> 
 <td>%s</td> 
 <td>%s</td> 
 <td>%s</td>  
 <td>%s</td>   
 </tr>';

echo sprintf($html, 
  $count, 
  $row1[size], 
  $row1['SerialNo'],
  $row1['InHouseBranding'], 
  $row1['BrandCode'],  
  $row1['size'], 
  $row1['Pattern'], 
  $row1['EntryStatus']
);
```

but thats only when youre in the context of a function or a class. If youre in the context of a template directly outputting html then its better to  switch back and forth:

```
<tr id="gridRow">
 <td><?php echo $count ?></td>
 <td> <input type="checkbox" onClick="selectAndUpdate('<?php echo $row1['size'] ?>')"></td>
 <td><?php echo $row1['SerialNo']</td> 
 <td><?php echo $row1['InHouseBranding'] ?></td> 
 <td><?php echo $row1['BrandCode'] ?></td> 
 <td><?php echo $row1['size'] ?></td> 
 <td> <?php echo $row1['Pattern'] ?></td>  
 <td><?php echo $row1['EntryStatus'] ?></td>   
</tr>
```